# Is there a way to make a post request to a http rest API from inside of an office js excel addin?

Tags: javascript, office-js, excel-addins

I am trying to make a post request from inside of my javascript file within my office excel add-in. I am able to easily do this in node using fetch but I cannot figure out how to do this from base js. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is an example of what I have tried so far:

```
function toAPI(json){
    var url = "http://someAPI";
    //this is what i did in node
    fetch(url, {
        headers: {headers here}
        method: "post"
        body: JSON.stringify(json)
    });

    //using xmlhttprequest
    xml = new XML HttpRequest();
    xml("post",url,true);
    xml.setRequestHeader(header here);
    xml.send(JSON.stringify(json));
 }
```

Comment: office js add-ins are just javascript and web browser based apps. you can do whatever you want to - just normal ajax applies.

Comment: do you have a link to somewhere I could learn how to do this? I tried making an async function and got a syntax error.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and what the issue is

Comment: I updated it to show you what I have used in the past. I have never used JS without node so I feel very lost.

Comment: `hmlhttp("post",url,true")` is a good hint

Comment: That was a typo :)

Comment: @AlonEitan posted a good hint on where you might be getting tripped up. Also, this is an aside from your question, but I highly recommend using Microsoft EdgeDev Preview for debugging for officejs if you don't already use it.

Comment: I am confused, I thought xmlhttprequest requires npm?

Comment: I saw you changed hml to xml, but you still have a double quote after true that would throw a syntax error:    xml("post",url,true")   <-- here

Comment: thanks frank, fixed the syntax error for clarity but that isnt the real problem im having